# Django forms validation is not showing up in the template

Tags: django, forms, validation, templates

My problem is, when I validate forms for errors, some text with warning would show up, But id does not. I was searching for some good answers and I tried also everything.

I was trying to implement validation in my register subpage so....

**First is my model.py for registration**

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Login: " + self.name + \
               " | e-mail: " + self.email + \
               " | password: " + self.password
```

**Second is my inputForms.py with simple validation**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import User


class NewUser(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    pic1 = forms.CharField(required=True)
    pic2 = forms.CharField(required=True)
    pic3 = forms.CharField(required=True)
    pic4 = forms.CharField(required=True)
    pic5 = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'password')

    def clean_email(self):
        email_passed = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_req = "yourdomain.com"
        if not email_req in email_passed:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Not a valid email. Please try again")
        return email_passed
```

**Third is my view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from definitions import SITE_ROOT
from .models import User
from . import inputForms
from threading import Thread
import base64
import re
import os


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'NewUser': inputForms.NewUser})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Kniznica')


def new_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = inputForms.NewUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            user_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user_password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            thread = Thread(target=save_user, args=(form, user_name, user_email, user_password, ))
            thread.start()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Kniznica')
        else:
            return render(request, "register.html", {'NewUser': inputForms.NewUser})


def save_user(form, user_name, user_email, user_password):
    base_to_png(form.cleaned_data['pic1'], user_name, "face1.png")
    base_to_png(form.cleaned_data['pic2'], user_name, "face2.png")
    base_to_png(form.cleaned_data['pic3'], user_name, "face3.png")
    base_to_png(form.cleaned_data['pic4'], user_name, "face4.png")
    base_to_png(form.cleaned_data['pic5'], user_name, "face5.png")
    user_instance = User.objects.create(name=user_name, email=user_email, password=user_password)
    user_instance.save()


def base_to_png(base64_string, name, image_name):
    string_without_header = re.sub('^data:image/.+;base64,', '', base64_string)
    img_data = base64.b64decode(string_without_header)
    if not os.path.exists(SITE_ROOT + "/faceId/" + name):
        os.makedirs(SITE_ROOT + "/faceId/" + name)
    filename = SITE_ROOT + "/faceId/" + name + "/" + image_name
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img_data)
    os.chdir(SITE_ROOT + "\static\scripts")
    os.system("node face-detection.js " + name + " " + image_name)
```

**And fourth is my template.html for registration**

```
<div>
    <form action="newUser" method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}
        {% if form.errors %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p> {{ errors }} </p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            Meno:{{ NewUser.name }}
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            Email:{{ NewUser.email }}
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            Heslo:{{ NewUser.password }}
        </div>
        <div hidden>
            {{ NewUser.pic1 }}
            {{ NewUser.pic2 }}
            {{ NewUser.pic3 }}
            {{ NewUser.pic4 }}
            {{ NewUser.pic5 }}
        </div>
        <div>
            <video id="video" width="300" height="300" autoplay></video>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="counter"></p>
            <button type="button" id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
            <button type="submit" id="save" name="register">Registrácia</button>
        </div>
        <canvas hidden id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: PLEASE! do not post code as screenshots, ESPECIALLY when there are 4 of them. Nobody will even look at your question this way

Comment: My answer is eddited.

Comment: There's some odd things in your view. Show the rest of that function though.

Comment: I edited view.py code and added there whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unusual view structure here - normally you would use the same view for displaying the initial form as you would for processing the submission and displaying errors.

But nevertheless, you do have a couple of obvious issues. Firstly, in your new_user view, when the form is not valid you don't send that invalid form back, but instead send the form class itself. You should always send an instance of the form anyway, and in this case you should send back the same instance you have already validated, because that's the thing with the errors:

```
return render(request, "register.html", {'NewUser': form})
```

Secondly, in your template, you are inconsistent about what you call the form. When you render the fields, you access it via `NewUser`. But in trying to display the errors, for some reason you call it `form`. As you have used the name NewUser when you send it from the view, you should use that to display the errors:

```
{{ NewUser.errors }}
```

Comment: One more question if i can. How can i print specific error under specific inputfield? has every error some id?

Comment: Sure, you can just access them via the field itself - for instance, `{{ NewUser.name.errors }}` for the name field.